# I keep getting an error next to the return VARCHAR(4)

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, plsqldeveloper

ERROR IS BETWEEN THE VARCHAR2 AND THE (4) seems to be a syntax error.

create or replace

```
    FUNCTION Employee_exists
        (p_employee_id IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2(4);

    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT employee_id
        FROM employees
        WHERE employee_id = p_employee_id;
        RETURN 'true';
    END Employee_exists;
```

Comment: @llya Still receiving the error

Comment: The error is between VARCHAR2 "here" (4); and there <---

Comment: try removing the semicolon after RETURN VARCHAR2(4); ... make it like RETURN VARCHAR2(4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two errors:

1. You can't specify the length of the return type in a function or procedure specification
2. `;` is a statement terminator, as such it has no place between the return type and `AS`

Your first line should be:

```
FUNCTION employee_exists
        (p_employee_id IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
```

Comment: So how would I specify the length later in the code and thank you very much

Comment: You could use a type that has a known fixed length, such as a boolean. You could also use a custom type like an SQL object or a PLSQL record. Currently if you use a standard type or a subtype, the length of the return type is not saved nor enforced.

Comment: In #2, you say that `;` is a line terminator. But in the OP's code, the particular semicolon you are talking about does terminate a line, therefore it would seem all right to have it there. The truth is, however, that a semicolon is a *statement* (not *line*) terminator, and it cannot be placed after the VARCHAR2(4) because that's not the end of the *statement* (the CREATE FUNCTION one).

Comment: @AndriyM you're right, "line terminator" is a poor choice of word in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
    create or replace function test_fun(id in number)
    return long
    as
    disp_price long;
    Begin
    select price into disp_price from orders
    where id=2;
    return disp_price;
    end test_fun;

-----------------------------------------------------------
OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------
declare
m_price long;
begin
m_price:=test_fun(1);
end;
```